# How to mock/patch the class variable of a mocked/patched object?

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

The `dir1/a.py` is a class to be tested. I will need to mock/patch the class.

**dir1/a.py**

```
from somemodule import get_c

@dataclass
class A:
    x: int
    y: object
    c: ClassVar[C] = get_c()  # get_c() need to be mocked/patched
```

**test_1.py**

```
@pytest.fixture
def sut() -> A:
    x = 1
    y = Mock()
    return A(x, y)

def test_...(sut):  # get_c() is called
    ''' '''
```

**test_2.py**

```
@patch('dir.a.A')
def test_...():  # get_c() is called
```

How to mock/patch `A.c` in the tests?

Comment: You can patch `dir1.get_c`, see [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6).

Comment: Thanks, @MrBean Bremen !  That link was very useful for me, it answers my question on how to patch a function  imported by a class that my test program is importing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `c: ClassVar[C] = get_c()` is in the declaration of the `A` dataclass at the top-level of the `dir1/a.py` file, it gets run when the module is imported. So `get_c` will be called unless you take extreme measures (implementing a [custom import loader](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#loaders), or patching the `dataclass` decorator before the `import dir1.a` gets called, ...).

If you don't want `get_c` to ever be called in your tests, the best and simpler solution is to change the code of `dir1/a.py` to not do it.

If it is OK for `get_c` to be called, but that the methods on it should not be used, it becomes simpler : just replace the `c` default value of your `A` dataclass with one of your own.

```py
import pytest
import unittest.mock as mocking
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import ClassVar, TypeVar


C = TypeVar('C')


def get_c():
    print("`get_c` called")
    return "THING TO MOCK"


@dataclass
class A:
    x: int
    y: object
    c: ClassVar[C] = get_c()


@pytest.fixture
def sut() -> A:
    x = 1
    y = mocking.Mock()
    a = A(x, y)
    a.c = mocking.Mock()   # change the value of `c`
    return a


def test_a(sut):
    assert isinstance(sut.c, mocking.Mock)
```